# wpf target property dependency

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to create a simple `Bindable` property called `MyBoolValue` in my `UserControl` class

First, here the xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TMDE.Controls.SimNaoRadioPicker"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="16"
              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox  Grid.Column="0" Content="Teste" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyBoolValue}" x:Name="chk" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here the code-behind:

```
public partial class SimNaoRadioPicker : UserControl
{

   public SimNaoRadioPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }  

   public bool? MyBoolValue
   {
       get
       {
           return (bool?)GetValue(MyCustomPropertyProperty);
       }
       set
       {
           SetValue(MyCustomPropertyProperty, value);
       }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyCustomProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomPropertyProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("MyBoolValue", 
       typeof(bool?), typeof(SimNaoRadioPicker), 
       new UIPropertyMetadata(MyPropertyChangedHandler));


   public static void MyPropertyChangedHandler(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       // Get instance of current control from sender
       // and property value from e.NewValue

       // Set public property on TaregtCatalogControl, e.g.
       ((SimNaoRadioPicker)sender).chk.IsChecked = (bool?)e.NewValue;
   }      
}
```

Now, when a try to use this control in another Window, like this:

```
    <my:SimNaoRadioPicker x:Name="test" MyBoolValue="{Binding QCV_Localizacao_Reutilizacao}"  Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,456,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="167" />
```

the Binding doesnt working, the property QCV_Localizacao_Reutilizacao doesnt get update and vice-versa.

The DataContext of the Window its a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so the
property "QCV_Localizacao_Reutilizacao" should work ok.

Also if I use a regular CheckBox instead of my UserControl, its works okay

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using FrameworkPropertyMetaData instead of UIPropertyMetadata?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the nullable part of the boolean and just make it a boolean, then set binding modes to two way.

Comment: i tried what you said but nothing changes. Also i dont think the property is the nullable since IsChecked its also nullable like the "QCV_Localizacao_Reutilizacao" property.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major issues -

**First**, your binding mode needs to be `TwoWay` which you can achieve in two ways -

Either specifed it to be `TwoWay in xaml` like this -

```
<my:SimNaoRadioPicker MyBoolValue="{Binding QCV_Localizacao_Reutilizacao,
                                              Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The `drawback` with above apporach is that you have to explicitly set the mode whenever you are using the UserControl's instance.

Another approach would be to modify your DP itself to say that it always be bind by default in a TwoWay mode like this using `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` -

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomPropertyProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("MyBoolValue", 
       typeof(bool?), typeof(SimNaoRadioPicker), 
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                            MyPropertyChangedHandler));
```

**Secondly**, `QCV_Localizacao_Reutilizacao` property lies in your Window's DataContext. But, by default any control will look for binding in its own dataContext so you explicilty need to tell it to look into Window's DataContext using `RelativeSource` like this -

```
<my:SimNaoRadioPicker MyBoolValue="{Binding QCV_Localizacao_Reutilizacao,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                     AncestorType=Window}/>
```